# manipulating an html select with Selenium WebDriver in Firefox does not work correctly

Tags: c#, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I'm using Selenium 3.6 and Selenium.Firefox.WebDriver 0.19 , with .Net C# .
i have the following code:

```
                foreach (var item in select)
                {
                    if (item.Displayed && item.Enabled)
                    {
                        Thread.Sleep(1000);
                        int x = item.Location.X;
                        int y = item.Location.Y;
                        ElementInfo.ClickItem(item);
                        SelectElement selOption = new SelectElement(item);
                        if (selOption.Options.Count == 1 && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(selOption.Options[selOption.Options.Count - 1].Text))
                        {
                            selOption.SelectByIndex(0);
                        }
                        else if (selOption.Options.Count > 1)
                        {
                            selOption.SelectByIndex(selOption.Options.Count - 1);

                        }
                    }
                }
```

It is used for making sure selecting elements in a custom html form works properly. The code works perfectly when run against Chrome, and fails with Firefox 56.0.1 (64-bit).

Please help.

Comment: Where is it failing? What is the exception?

Comment: It does not select the correct value.  selOption.SelectByIndex don't work.